# Visual Studio Code ESLint Extension: Use .gitignore as .eslintignore?

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, eslint

Is it possible to use `.gitignore` instead of `.eslintignore`, in the [ESLint Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)?

I know it is possible when using eslint from the command line:

```
eslint --ignore-path .gitignore
```

I am just wondering if it is possible to do the same in the ESLint VSC extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this setting on vsCode settings by adding:

```
"eslint.options": {
    "ignorePath": ".gitignore"
}
```

To your user settings.

Comment: Altough recently this started to give me error ENOENT, but the file is there

Comment: I believe this will only use the top level .gitignore.

Comment: That is correct, although multiple .gitignore files has been requested, seems there is no plan on working on those changes right now (e.g. [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9794) and [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13389))

If you need to use several .gitignore files on you linter config, maybe you could give [eslint-gitignore](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-gitignore) a change.